# Own padding not working on b-sidebar (vue)

Tags: css, vue.js, padding, sidebar

I am using bootstrap-vue and would like to add some padding to my sidebar, but i cant get it to work.
If I add padding in the browser devtools, it does.
But my code wont go through to the browser, so it does not show there at all.

I have tried to give it a class myself -> ends up in at the main tag with class: "b-sidebar-outer"
->Doesnt help, because i need it to go to the one with "b-sidebar"

But if i do this (or as specific as possible with classes):

```
.b-sidebar {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

-> not showing

I *could* give the padding to the elements inside my sidebar, but that would be a lot more work. :c

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you share more of your css? there might be something overriding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue.JS gives every component and unique uid. In your DevTools you will see that components are having a data attribute, when your CSS is parsed it will look something like this `div[data-v-f3f3eg9]`.

This way multiple components can use the same class names without intervening with eachother.

To set a style in another component you can use a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

For SCSS:

```
/deep/ .b-sidebar {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

For CSS:

```
.your-class >>> .b-sidebar {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Havent payed attention to that "scoped" before, will brush up my knowledge on that now. (: